# Magento2 installation wizard hanged on 90%

Tags: magento2, setup

I was installing Magento2 and the installation reached 90% and it staid there not moving for more than 15 minutes with no errors in the log console.

I have read on the Internet that I have to increase the value of max_execution_time in php.ini file to `18000 instead of 30`.

I did, and restarted apache, then tried to open `127.0.0.1` hoping it will get me to that setup page again, but unfortunately I got `"Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page" page`.

I've tried `127.0.0.1/setup`, but I got

> "Welcome to Magento Admin, your online store headquarters. To use the
>   Magento setup wizard sign into your Admin account and navigate to
>   System => Tools => Web Setup Wizard"

So I tried `127.0.0.1/admin` (I've changed the administrator page to admin in the setup wizard) but I got **"Not Found" page**.

What should I do now :(

Comment: DO you have mod_rewrite turned on?

Comment: Can you check for error logs of apache and also in magento? there might me a clue there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: installation stuck at 65% "installing user configuration"](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119618/magento-2-installation-stuck-at-65-installing-user-configuration)

Answer (score 0):

Since the installation was not completed, try reinstalling magento

1. Ssh into the server and delete the database
2. Delete your config files

   - app/etc/env.php
   - app/etc/config.php
3. Try the installation again (127.0.0.1/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Every time this sort of thing has happened to me it's been php timing out. I know you changed `max_execution_time` but what about `max_input_time` and `memory_limit`?

For me on MAMP i run:

```
max_execution_time = 9000
max_input_time = 9000
memory_limit = 16G
```

and M2 installs fine. Also, make sure you have the right `php.ini` as there are a few on most systems and you might not be editing the one that php is loading.