# Magento 2: installation stuck at 65% "installing user configuration"

Tags: magento2, installation, php-7, magento-2.0.7

So I recently installed Ubuntu 16.04 on an old laptop.

Running PHP 7:

```
PHP 7.0.4-7ubuntu2.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v2.4.0, Copyright (c) 2002-2016, by Derick Rethans
```

I'm trying to install Magento 2.0.7 but my installation is stuck at 65%

[image]

I've increased the memory allocated to PHP to 768M as suggested by the official doc but still stuck.

There's nothing in the Magento logs, nothing in the apache error logs.

In the firebug console tab, I can see that there are POST calls every few seconds to `/setup/index.php/install/progress` where the response is always the same and represents the progress listed in the console log.

There's also a POST call to `/setup/index.php/session/prolong` from time to time where the response is always:

```
{"success":false}
```

I don't usually post that kind of installation questions but to be honest, I'm running out of ideas regarding what it could be.

Let's assume I don't have access to command line and I absolutely want to install via the web setup wizard. I want to know what is causing this issue and how to fix it

Comment: I am also facing same issue with Ubuntu 14.04 . Magento 2.0.7 for several times ends up 89%.

Comment: If its not progress you should stop process and try to run `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` this will install rest of the module. Or if UI is not working you should try to install with command line with `php bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://127.0.0.1/magento2/ \
--db-host=localhost --db-name=magento --db-user=magento --db-password=magento \
--admin-firstname=Magento --admin-lastname=User --admin-email=user@example.com \
--admin-user=admin --admin-password=admin123 --language=en_US \
--currency=USD --timezone=America/Chicago --use-rewrites=1`

Comment: Reference - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-install.html

Comment: is rewrite_module enabled?

Comment: @aman_uni yeah I've installed M2 several times before and used the command line in the past but

Comment: How you are installing it ? via composer or via complete bundle / package ?  from magento website ?

Comment: @webkul archive downloaded directly from Magento website

Comment: have you tried to increase memory limit of php for example 1028M

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to @Nickool, I **found out apache `mod_rewrite` was not enabled**.

So I ran:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Added the following lines to my `/etc/apache2/sites-available/my.host.com`

```
    <Directory /var/www/html/m2>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Then ran:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

And now the installation is finishing.

The `mod_rewrite` requirement is stated here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

But not here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html

I reckon the doc needs a small update

Comment: cool! since it happened to me once :)

Comment: @raphael-at-digital-pianism open a PR for the docs then. The documentation team is extremely responsive, and open to receiving assistance from the community. An opportunity that shouldn't be missed! ;).