# Why can't I finish installation?

Tags: magento2, magento-community, installation, install-script

I'm trying to install Magento 2 with sample data on my linux desktop and web based installation always hangs on the 65 to 67% range.

My `/var/www/html/magento` folder has 777 permissions for all files and directories and on `.htaccess`, on the root magento folder, I have defined:

```
php_value memory_limit 2048M
php_value max_execution_time 18000
```

Both apache and php were installed via apt-get. And the php modules were installed to comply with pre installation check.

For php install test purposes, I created the standard phpinfo.php file with `<?php phpinfo(); ?>`. But I installed php 7.0 from apt's repository. Would this be an issue?

Also, when I try CLI installation, I use this command:

```
bin/magento setup:install --base-url=http://localhost --backend-frontname=backend --admin-user=master --admin-firstname=Admin --admin-lastname=Admin --admin-email=an.email@server.com --admin-password=7-digitStrongPassword --db-host=localhost --db-user=magento --db-name=magento --db-password=magentoUser
```

The CLI installation finishes successfully but I still can't access the local application.

Being a Java developer, I'm not php-wise savvy. What am I missing here?

Comment: I had the same issue maybe that could help: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/119618/2380