# Magento 2 installation fails for Sample Data

Tags: magento2

I'm trying to fresh install Magento 2 on my server with Sample Data and installation keeps failing at around 67%. Here's what I've done so far -

1. I downloaded Magento 2.1 with Sample Data from the official download
   page (~200 MB) and uploaded it to my server.
2. I extracted the archive in a folder, created a new database and user and ran the setup.
3. Did the usual configuration and entered my information and at step 6,
   began the install process. It ran till 67% and then gave me an error
   [image: Magento 2 Error] Which doesn't tell much. The log is
   identical to the one on [this similar question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/132555/magento-fresh-installation) and I've tried
   the solution mentioned there with no luck.

I've tried this installation 3 times but get the same result. Any ideas?

**Edit:** I was requested the complete console log in the comments. It was the exact same thing as in the linked question above so I didn't pasted it in the first place. I ran the installer again to get my hands on the log and got a few steps ahead this time. I ofcourse dropped all tables before restarting installer again.

```
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...

Required extensions check...

Enabling Maintenance Mode...

Installing deployment configuration...

Cleaning up database...
Cleaning up database `vipul_magento2`

Installing database schema:
Schema creation/updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Theme':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Customer':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Cms':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Search':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Quote':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Widget':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_User':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Sales':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_Email':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_Tax':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Vault':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Security':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Weee':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Persistent':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Captcha':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Reports':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':

Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Integration':
Installing schema... Upgrading schema... 

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesSampleData':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_TaxSampleData':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_CmsSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Translation':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_SalesSampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_WidgetSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Installing schema... 

Module 'Magento_WishlistSampleData':

Schema post-updates:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':

Module 'Magento_Theme':

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':

Module 'Magento_Customer':

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Cms':

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Quote':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Widget':

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_User':

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':

Module 'Magento_Authorization':

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':

Module 'Magento_Sales':

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':

Module 'Magento_Checkout':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':

Module 'Magento_Tax':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Weee':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_Paypal':

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Reports':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':

Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':

Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ThemeSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ProductLinksSampleData':

Module 'Magento_ReviewSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Integration':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_SendFriend':

Module 'Magento_Shipping':

Module 'Magento_Sitemap':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Swagger':

Module 'Magento_Swatches':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesLayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_SwatchesSampleData':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProductSampleData':

Module 'Magento_TaxImportExport':

Module 'Magento_TaxSampleData':

Module 'Magento_GoogleAdwords':

Module 'Magento_CmsSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Translation':

Module 'Magento_GoogleOptimizer':

Module 'Magento_Ups':

Module 'Magento_UrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_SalesRuleSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Usps':

Module 'Magento_Variable':

Module 'Magento_Braintree':

Module 'Magento_Version':

Module 'Magento_Webapi':

Module 'Magento_WebapiSecurity':

Module 'Magento_SalesSampleData':

Module 'Magento_CatalogWidget':

Module 'Magento_WidgetSampleData':

Module 'Magento_Wishlist':
Running schema recurring...

Module 'Magento_WishlistSampleData':


Installing user configuration...

Enabling caches:
Current status:
Array
(
[config] => 1
[layout] => 1
[block_html] => 1
[collections] => 1
[reflection] => 1
[db_ddl] => 1
[eav] => 1
[customer_notification] => 1
[full_page] => 1
[config_integration] => 1
[config_integration_api] => 1
[translate] => 1
[config_webservice] => 1
)


Installing data...
Data install/update:
Module 'Magento_Store':

Module 'Magento_AdvancedPricingImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Directory':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Theme':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Backend':

Module 'Magento_Backup':

Module 'Magento_Eav':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Customer':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_BundleImportExport':

Module 'Magento_AdminNotification':

Module 'Magento_CacheInvalidate':

Module 'Magento_Indexer':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Cms':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Catalog':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Rule':

Module 'Magento_Msrp':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Search':

Module 'Magento_Bundle':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Quote':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogUrlRewrite':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Widget':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_SalesSequence':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CheckoutAgreements':

Module 'Magento_Payment':

Module 'Magento_SampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CmsUrlRewrite':

Module 'Magento_Config':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Downloadable':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogSearch':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Contact':

Module 'Magento_Cookie':

Module 'Magento_Cron':

Module 'Magento_CurrencySymbol':

Module 'Magento_User':
Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_CustomerImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CustomerSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Deploy':

Module 'Magento_Developer':

Module 'Magento_Dhl':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Authorization':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_CatalogInventory':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ImportExport':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRule':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Sales':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Email':

Module 'Magento_EncryptionKey':

Module 'Magento_Fedex':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_GiftMessage':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Checkout':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_GoogleAnalytics':

Module 'Magento_Ui':

Module 'Magento_GroupedImportExport':

Module 'Magento_GroupedProduct':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_Tax':
Installing data... Upgrading data... 

Module 'Magento_DownloadableImportExport':

Module 'Magento_Vault':

Module 'Magento_Security':

Module 'Magento_LayeredNavigation':

Module 'Magento_Marketplace':

Module 'Magento_MediaStorage':

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_MsrpSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Multishipping':

Module 'Magento_NewRelicReporting':

Module 'Magento_Newsletter':

Module 'Magento_OfflinePayments':

Module 'Magento_SalesRule':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_OfflineShipping':

Module 'Magento_PageCache':

Module 'Magento_Weee':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Paypal':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Persistent':

Module 'Magento_ProductAlert':

Module 'Magento_CatalogSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ProductVideo':

Module 'Magento_Captcha':

Module 'Magento_Reports':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_RequireJs':

Module 'Magento_Review':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_DownloadableSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_Rss':

Module 'Magento_CatalogRuleConfigurable':

Module 'Magento_Authorizenet':

Module 'Magento_OfflineShippingSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_BundleSampleData':
Installing data... 

Module 'Magento_ConfigurableSampleData':
Installing data...
```

According to [this page in the Magento Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/trouble/tshoot_sample-data.html), the cause for this problem is a low amount of execution time, it suggessts more than 600s but I have it on 180000.

Comment: Can you please paste the errors of console log clearly.

Comment: Hello Veek, do you check console log for error?

Comment: Editted my question with more info. Please check

Comment: Make sure that when you extract the downloaded file without any error.  Sometimes extraction exit  with displaying the error code.

Answer (score 1):

> Enable apache mod_rewrite

Then run

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

You can find more information at [Raphael answer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/119618/magento-2-installation-stuck-at-65-installing-user-configuration)

Other option is you can install Magento 2  by [composer](http://magenticians.com/installing-magento-2-composer).

Hope it helps.

Comment: It should be enabled. I have these lines in the htaccess file     `Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on`

Comment: @Veek download the fresh package by composer and install.

Comment: Do you mean to say that I can't use the web utility for installation? I have no experience with composer, I would really prefer the web setup over it.

Comment: @ VeeK You can use web utility as well, Download the package from composer and install it by web or Download code with out sample data and try. The issue may cause while sample data installation.

Comment: Do you have an `AllowOverride` statement?

Answer (score 0):

Please check below link and then try to install. Also Change in php.ini.

```
max_execution_time = 1800
max_input_time = 1800
memory_limit = 1024M

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache.html
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html
```

Comment: Please read the question carefully. i've already done this and system requirements are fulfilled.

Comment: And you restarted the web server?